# how to declare count so it won't re-declared each click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i want to make  when that on click will replace to "count is odd!" or "count is even"
but how i should declare count so it won't reinitialized to 1 each click event?

here is what i came with:

```
    <h1 onclick="var count=1; 
                 if (count%2==1) {
                       this.innerHTML='count is odd!'; count++;}
                 else{     
                 this.innerHTML='count is even';count++;} ">
    Click on this text</h1>
```

now what happens as you can see is that count is one on each click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, the `counter` variable is in `onclick` closure scope and thus it will act like a global variable for all `onclick` events.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")
for (var key in elements)
{
    if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        var counter = 1;
        elements[key].onclick = function()
        {
            var oddEven = (counter++ % 2 == 1) ? "odd" : "even";

            elements[key].innerHTML = "count is " + oddEven;
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: You don't need `onclick`inline code your elements.*

Comment: Dont use for-in loops as a for-each loop.

Comment: Can you please explain, its unknown to me

Comment: I thought you already knew that because of the added hasOwnProperty check. for-in iterates over all the keys of an object. This might include stuff other then the indexes and is not guaranteed to be in the correct order. For arrays the correct idiom is `var i; (for i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` or a iteration method/function like arr.forEach

Answer (score 2):

Mixing markup and javascript in this way is pretty bad. I would recommend you separating logic:

```
<h1 id="myH">Click on this text</h1>
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
var count = 1;
window.onload = function() {
    var myH = document.getElementById('myH');
    myH.onclick = function() {
        if (count % 2 == 1) {
            myH.innerHTML = 'count is odd!'; 
        } else {
            myH.innerHTML = 'count is even';
        }
        count++;
    };
};
```